# Add two sum case statements that are of a negative value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add two select statements with onyl negative values, these are the statements:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '8420000' THEN amount < 0 END) 
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '8400000' THEN amount < 0 END) AS Payments
```

I have tried :

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '8400000,8420000' THEN amount < 0 END) AS Payments
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`THEN amount < 0` doesn't make much sense. If I understood you correctly, what you want is:

```
SUM(CASE 
       WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 
       THEN amount 
    END) As Payments
```